# How to append key value to the result of factory()->make() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am writting a Test Case.

Lets say there is a **Threads model** with fields: **user_id, title, body**

So to test wheather submitting the Thread works, I am doing this:

```
$user = factory('App\User')->create();
$thread = factory('App\Thread')->make(['user_id' => $user->id]);
$this->post('/threads', $thread->toArray());

$this->get('/thread/'.$thread->id)
            ->assertSee($thread->title)
```

But I have yet another field that I want to post along with the thread which is not part of the thread model.

eg.

```
community => 'some_community'
```

So how do I append another field before posting the array to `/threads`.

**How can I append key value pair to the result of make() ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [data_set](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-data-set) function:

```
$thread = factory('App\Thread')->make(['user_id' => $user->id]);
$payload = $thread->toArray();

$this->post('/threads', data_set($payload, 'community', 'some_community'));
```